# Finding $\frac{\partial ^8 f}{\partial x^4\partial y^4}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

> Given the function $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{1-xy}$ find the value of$\frac{\partial ^8 f}{\partial x^4\partial y^4}(0,0)$.

First I developed the function into a taylor series using geometric series around $(0,0)$: $$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{1-xy}=\displaystyle{\sum_{n=0}^\infty(xy)^n}$$. The taylor approximation of order 8 is given by $$f(x,y)\thickapprox\displaystyle{\sum_{n=0}^4(xy)^n}=1+xy+(xy)^2+(xy)^3+(xy)^4$$, where the degree of the last element is 8 so indeed we got the approximation. It's the taylor series by its singularity. looking at the element in original taylor series deriving 4 times by x and 4 by y is the only term which is with coefficient 1 (all other derivatives exist twice since around $(0,0)$ f is continuous and so its derivatives). So prima facie $$\frac{\partial ^8 f}{\partial x^4\partial y^4}=8!\cdot 1=40320$$ but mypad claims that $\frac{\partial ^8 f}{\partial x^4\partial y^4}=576$. Where am I mistaken?

Comment: The coefficient should be $4!4!$ not $8!$

Comment: but the form of the terms of 8th degree is $\frac{1}{8!}(x^8\frac{\partial ^8 f}{\partial x^8}+x\cdot y^7\frac{\partial^8 f}{\partial y \partial x^7}+\dots+y^8 \frac{\partial ^8 f}{\partial y^8})$. isn't it?

Comment: Almost, there are $\binom{8}{k}$ ways of taking $$\frac{\partial^8 f}{\partial x^k\partial y^{8-k}}.$$ So you have $$\frac{1}{8!}\left(x^8\frac{\partial^8 f}{\partial x^8}+\dots+\binom{8}{4}\frac{\partial^8 f}{\partial x^4\partial y^{4}}+\dots+y^8\frac{\partial^8 f}{\partial y^{8}}\right).$$ So the $$\frac{\partial^8 f}{\partial x^4\partial y^4}$$ term is multiplied by $$\frac{1}{8!}\binom{8}{4}=\frac{1}{4!4!}$$

Comment: Now I understood, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial^4 x^4y^4}{\partial x^4}=y^4\frac{\partial^4 x^4}{\partial x^4}=24y^4$$
$$\frac{\partial^4 24y^4}{\partial y^4}=24\times 24 = 576$$

Comment: Can you explain more please? I'm not sure I understood to the end.

Comment: This is just your $\frac{\partial ^8 (xy)^4}{\partial x^4\partial y^4}$ calculated in two steps (using $\frac{\partial ^4 x^4}{\partial x^4} = 4! = 24$ etc). I added an intermediate step.